# How to change display value of the Submit button on page load using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery and need suggestions on following requirement.

I have a form with a submit button as below. Page accepts `locale` as an input parameter. Depending on the value of `locale`, on page load I am populating the labels of the input fields in respective language using `jQuery.i18n.properties.js` plug-in, but I could not update the display value of the button.

Please suggest solution or if there is another way to achieve this.

HTML code:

```js
<input type="submit" data-inline="true" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Have tried below jQuery options to update the button label:

1. `$("#submit").val($.i18n.prop('submit'));`
2. `$("#submit").html($.i18n.prop('submit'));`
3. `$("#submit").prop('value',($.i18n.prop('submit')));`
4. `$("#submit").text($.i18n.prop('submit'));`

None of them worked. But I see the value gets updated as below in Developer tools window, for this button.

`<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
Submit
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="New Text">
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#submit")[0].value = $.i18n.prop('submit');`. Does that work for you?

(Even though it's a JS workaround, not a JQuery solution)

Comment: It didn't work M. Though I can see the value property got updated for this button in Chrome's Developer tools window. Do we need to refresh this component ?

Comment: That's a very strange behavior, I tested it on both FF and Chrome, where it seems to work for me. The code written above can, by the way, easily be transferred to pure JS with `docuement.querySelector("#submit').value = $.i18n.prop('submit');`-

Answer (score 0):

If your button is an `input` tag, use the jQuery `val`:

```js
function changeBtnText() {
  $("#submit").val("My new button text");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="My button">
<button type="button" onclick="changeBtnText()">Change button text</button>
```

If your button is a `button` tag, use the jQuery `text` (or `html`):

```js
function changeBtnText() {
  $("#submit").text("My new button text");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="submit">My button</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeBtnText()">Change button text</button>
```

Note: I recommend giving your button an ID different from "submit" to avoid confusion.